# Suppress exponential formatting in figure ticks

Tags: matlab, plot, label, number-formatting

Tick labels for ticks bigger than about 10'000, get formatted to 1x10^4 for example. Whereas the exponential part appears above the corresponding axes. This misbehavior has been well described on [on matlab central](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/270088) as well, but without a solution.

Thanks for your help.

---

The 'quick trick'

```
set(gca, 'YTickLabel',get(gca,'YTick'))
```

did not work when applied to bar3, as can be seen on the following figure.

[image: bar3 plot failing]

Comment: Looking at the thread you link, I see `tick2text` (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16003-tick2text-create-easy-to-customize-tick-labels), which seems to perfectly solve the problem.

Comment: tick2text formats the tick labels, but the exponential part above the axis remains, which looks really odd. The news post given above notices the same issue.

Comment: The picture (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fx_files/16003/4/tick2textexample.png) that goes along with `tick2text` seems to indicate otherwise. Is the picture wrong?

Comment: Good point! Unfortunately I don't have the figure with the issue at hand. It's a bar3 plot with a colorbar and cmfreeze vodoo. I admit tweaking the graphic quite a bit.

Comment: The following sample code works as expected! I will check tick2text again with the real sample. 

y = cool(7);
fh = figure;
bar3(y*1E6,'detached');
ax = gca(fh);
tick2text(ax, 'ztickoffset' ,-1.15,'zformat', '%5.0f', 'axis','z')

Comment: @zellus: I'm adding this as an answer, for future reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to get better control over tick labels, and to avoid the exponential formatting, is to use [TICK2TEXT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/16003-tick2text-create-easy-to-customize-tick-labels) from the File Exchange.

Here's an example:

```
y = cool(7); %# define some data
ah = axes; %# create new axes and remember handle
bar3(ah,y*1E6,'detached'); %# create a 3D bar plot
tick2text(ah, 'ztickoffset' ,-1.15,'zformat', '%5.0f', 'axis','z') %# fix the tick labels
```

Answer (score 10):

**EDIT**

According to this [technical solution page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-16KCT/), the recommended way of formatting the tick labels is this (you can use any of the number formatting functions like NUM2STR, SPRINTF, MAT2STR, or any other..)

```
y = cool(7);
bar(y(:,1)*1e6)
set(gca, 'YTickMode','manual')
set(gca, 'YTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'YTick')'))
```

[image]

However there seems to be a bug when it comes to the Z-axis (the labels are correctly formatted, but the exponential multiplier is still showing for some reason!)

```
y = cool(7);
bar3(y*1e6, 'detached')
set(gca, 'ZTickMode','manual')
set(gca, 'ZTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'ZTick')'))
```

[image]

Finally, there's another workaround where we replace the tick labels with text objects (see this [technical solution page](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15TK6/index.html?solution=1-15TK6) as reference):

```
y = cool(7);
bar3(y*1e6, 'detached')
offset = 0.25; Xl=get(gca,'XLim'); Yl=get(gca,'YLim'); Zt=get(gca,'ZTick');
t = text(Xl(ones(size(Zt))),Yl(ones(size(Zt)))-offset,Zt, num2str(Zt')); %#'
set(t, 'HorizontalAlignment','right', 'VerticalAlignment','Middle')
set(gca, 'ZTickLabel','')
```

[image]

Comment: I appreciate your solution! While I was googling for a solution, I did hit the 'technical solution' you reference as well, but did not see its relevance. The issue is well prepared now to be filed to MathWorks support!

Answer (score 3):

One other trick you can try is to scale your data before you plot it, then scale the tick labels to make it appear that it is plotted on a different scale. You can use the function [LOG10](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/log10.html) to help you automatically compute an appropriate scale factor based on your plotted values. Assuming you have your data in variables `x` and `y`, you can try this:

```
scale = 10^floor(log10(max(y)));  %# Compute a scaling factor
plot(x,y./scale);                 %# Plot the scaled data
yTicks = get(gca,'YTick');        %# Get the current tick values
set(gca,'YTickLabel',num2str(scale.*yTicks(:),'%.2f'));  %# Change the labels
```

Comment: Good solution, but I might prefer to tackle the graphics part and not the data.

Comment: @zellus You ought to be able to use an `hgtransform` object to scale the displayed data too. That was the solution we ended up using. Plot data is unmolested, but displayed at 1/1000th its actual value.

Comment: Awesome. It is quite non-trivial how to transform the values on the axis.