# How to change the format of the numbers displayed on an axis in a MATLAB plot?

Tags: matlab, plot

I actually have 3 questions:

I have a plot with data that is in the thousands and my plot's axis is diplaying the tick marks as .4  .8  1.0  1.2  and a *10^4 in the lower right. This is a little annoying.

Besides dividing my data by 1000 or hardcodig the tick marks is there a way to change to tick marks from .4*10^4 TO 4000?

Seems like this should be trivial but aftter browsing through all of the figure's properties I can't seem to get an where.

And...once I get 4000 to apear instead of .4*10^4 is there a way to rotate the tick mark label so it is not overlapping the other labels.

And..how do you set how many "major" tick marks there are?

Thanks so much!

ME

Comment: This is largely covered in this other question: [Suppress exponential formatting in figure ticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588293/suppress-exponential-formatting-in-figure-ticks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
x=[4000, 8000, 10000, 12000]; % define the x values where you want to have a tick
set(gca,'XTick',x);  % Apply the ticks to the current axes
set(gca,'XTickLabel', arrayfun(@(v) sprintf('%d',v), x, 'UniformOutput', false) ); % Define the tick labels based on the user-defined format
```

Reference: [Mathworks](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-16KCT/?solution=1-16KCT)

In regards to the label rotation, it seems that Matlab does not support such feature by its own, but someone wrote [a script for the label rotation](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8722-rotate-tick-label), and you might want to give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

There's a nice function by Yair Altman called ticklabelformat to do that in case you want to still be able to freely play with the axes afterwards

description: 
http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/setting-axes-tick-labels-format/

and the download link: 
http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/36254-ticklabelformat-set-a-dynamic-format-of-axes-tick-labels