# How to present date as a string on matlab figure

Tags: string, datetime, matlab, figure

I have imported date&time data from a text file, in which it was stored as a string, to Matlab. I can convert string to numeric data and back, by using datenum and datestr commands.

My problem is with creating figures. I can easily plot data against numeric date&time values, but as it is stored as a number, it is not very useful. On the other hand, I found it impossible to plot data against strings. Is there a way that data would be plotted against numeric date&time value, but presented in a friendly way as a string?

Best regards,

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [datetick](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/datetick.html). Or you may prefer [rotate tick label](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8722-rotate-tick-label). More on tweaking tick labels is provided by [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588293/suppress-exponential-formatting-in-figure-ticks).

Comment: Yes, datetick converts numeric date&time data into strings. However, as I noticed, it does it only once, during the first plot. After plotting the figure, when it is zoomed, normal data gets new ticks (with a smaller step), while no new string ticks appear. Data cursor tool also returns only numeric data, not converted one. Is there a way to solve this problem?

Comment: Check the documentation for 'ResizeFcn'. Using *set(gcf, 'ResizeFcn', @resizeFunctionHandle)*' you may assign a function (handle) with the resize event. In this case *resizeFunctionHandle* is executed on every figure resize.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is you are asking for:

```
date_numeric = 1:5;
date_string={'date_1' 'date_2' 'date_3' 'date_4' 'date_5'};
y = rand(size(date_numeric));
plot(date_numeric, y, 'b')
set(gca, 'XTick',1:5, 'XTickLabel',date_string)
```

[image]