# Reposition yTickLabels in interactionplot

Tags: matlab, plot, label

I made an interactionplot in Matlab, but part of the `yTickLabels` are behind the plot. For example, you only see `10` instead of `10 x 10^-5`.

Any idea how i can solve this?

[image: http://i46.tinypic.com/t858ya.png]

Original picture: http://i46.tinypic.com/t858ya.png

Comment: you might consider making custom labels for your ticks,  trying this http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/15986, or spacing your plots farther apart

Comment: Similar questions: [Suppress exponential formatting in figure ticks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3588293/97160), [Matlab, how to adjust axis values on figures](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6495653/97160)

Comment: I actually like the scientific notation. I just want to move the axis ticks more to the left of the axis because the ticks are now just partly shown.

Comment: Thanks for your replies!

I actually like the scientific notation. I just want to move the axis ticks more to the left of the axis because the ticks are now just partly shown. Changing the spacing between them does help, but makes all my plots significantly smaller (need to set spacing to like 0.2). So just moving the ticklabels would be the best solution for me I think.

Answer (score 0):

I found and answer. Only the scientific notation block is behind the other graphs, but this block cannot be moved:
http://www.mathworks.nl/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PKVQ9/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-4PKVQ9

So the best alternative is to edit the labels of the graphs.