# matlab axis to percent

Tags: matlab

I have an axis on a 3D plot which I would like to plot in percent. Currently, the values are decimals. So for example, I would like 0.12 to be displayed as '12%'.

Currently, I am using:

```
  temp_zlabels=100*str2num(get(gca,'ZTickLabel'));
  set(gca, 'ZTickLabel', sprintf('%d%%|', temp_zlabels))
```

This works fine, but when make the chart bigger or rotate it, the axis values start over, instead of re-scaling.

So for example, if I have an axis (0% 25% 50% 75%), and I make the graph bigger, the axis now reads (0% 25% 50% 75% 0% 25% 50% 75%) instead of correctly re-scaling the original axis.

What is the best way to label the axis in percent, where I do not run into this problem?

Comment: related question: [Suppress exponential formatting in figure ticks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588293/suppress-exponential-formatting-in-figure-ticks)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to have `ZTick` matching your `ZTickLabel`:

```
set(gca, 'ZTick', temp_zlabels/100)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to fix the z-ticks positions:

```
set(gca, 'ZTickMode','manual')
```

---

Example:

```
D = rand(100,3);
plot3(D(:,1),D(:,2),D(:,3),'o'), box on, grid on
xlabel x, ylabel y, zlabel z

set(gca, 'ZTickMode','manual')
set(gca, 'ZTickLabel',num2str(100.*get(gca,'ZTick')','%g%%'))
rotate3d on
```

[image: screenshot]

Refer to [these](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-16KCT/) [pages](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-15HXQ/index.html?solution=1-15HXQ) for further explanations...