# Removing scientific notation in plot axis (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, plot, axis-labels, scientific-notation

I am trying to configure the yticklabels to appear on the graph in a non scientific notation format. My original plot looks like:

[image]

In order to remove the scientific notation, I have tried:

```
set(gca,'YTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'YTick').'))
```

but I get the following result:

[image]

As it can be seen here, this does not make any sense as the y axis values should increase.

I have also tried the following code:

```
yt=get(gca,'YTick');
set(gca,'YTickLabel',sprintf('%.1f\n',yt))
```

and I get the folowing result:

[image]

This does not make sense either. The top label is missing.

I cannot find the way to get it right. Any help would be appreciated.

**Edits:**
As my question has been identified as possible duplicate, I would like to add some other few remarks specific to my problem which I explain below.

If I try the following code:

```
yt = get(gca,'YTick');
set(gca,'YTickLabel', sprintf('%.1f|',yt))
```

In Matlab 2013b, it works. However, for some reason I do not obtain the same results when doing it in Matlab 2015a. 
In Matlab 2015a the above code would result in:

[image]

In Matlab 2015a, I also tried to slightly modify the above code using \n instead of |:

```
yt = get(gca,'YTick');
set(gca,'YTickLabel', sprintf('%.2f\n',yt))
```

where I obtain similar results as in Matlab 2013b. The only difference is that it misses the top label:
[image]

I think the problem is not the `set(gca,'YTickLabel', sprintf('%.2f\n',yt))` bit, I think the problem is in the  `yt = get(gca,'YTick')` where for some reason it only detects 3 labels instead of 4:

[image]

I have also tried the Matlab exchange function tick2text explained in: [Suppress exponential formatting in figure ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588293/suppress-exponential-formatting-in-figure-ticks)

But the results are not right either:

[image]

As it can be seen here, there are labels missing. I do not understand why the labels do not equally divide the y axis.

I would appreciate the people who think that my question in duplicate to say why at least. Because I have spent a while trying to explain my problem as clear as possible using different examples and images.

Comment: I already tried set(gca, 'YTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'YTick')')) which is explained in the above link.

Comment: So did the person say who asked that. Have you tried the accepted answer? and all other answers?

Comment: The person who asked it suggested set(gca, 'YTickLabel',get(gca,'YTick')), and I tried set(gca, 'YTickLabel',num2str(get(gca,'YTick')')) which is one of the answers. I do not know about the tick2text matlab exchange program, I am trying it now, when I came across that post I thought it was a solution for 3D graphs.

Comment: Maybe just divide your data by 1e5?

Comment: @Mercury: I do not think my problem is the formatting of the labels, I think my problem has to do with the yt=get(gca,'YTick'); bit. See Added information to my post.