# Can't seem to be able to force y axis to not be in exponent notation despite specifying it that way in my script. X axis works fine

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I'm making a scatterplot and want my x and y axes to not be displayed in scientific notation. When I put in the line of code which should fix this, only the x-axis is fixed, the y-axis is left untouched.

Tried using `ax.XAxis.Exponent = 0;`. Works for X but `ax.YAxis.Exponent = 0;` doesn't work. Also came across `XRuler` instead, but that didn't work either. Maybe it's worth noting that **changing the y-axis exponent to anything other than zero works perfectly as it should**.

```matlab
%-------------Make Plots-------------%

figure;
scatter(x, y, 30, magComp);
title('Compensated');


%---------------Plot Options----------------%

% axis equal
ax = gca;
ax.XAxis.Exponent = 0;
ax.YAxis.Exponent = 0;
c = colorbar();
c.Label.String = 'nT'
xlabel('Easting');
ylabel('Northing');
caxis([5.9e4 6e4]);
```

Any insight? Am new to MATLAB, so sorry for crappy code formatting. [Here is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7kvPk.jpg) of the output I'm getting (data boxed because it is IP). The x-axis is right, my y-axis is still in scientific notation.

Comment: The exponent parameter controls the number of zeros taken out of each tick label and put at the top of the axis. It does not control the formatting of each tick mark.

Comment: Also, I don’t think you should do what you’re trying to do, it is very hard to read numbers with that many digits. You are doing a disservice to your readers.

Comment: See also the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588293/suppress-exponential-formatting-in-figure-ticks

Comment: @CrisLuengo Thank you for your help. If that's the case, then why does it work for the x-axis? Normally I would agree with you on the formatting, but I believe convention for coordinates is to leave them as the full number!

Comment: I don’t know what convention is and I don’t know what data you are plotting. I just know it’s hard to read. The numbers along the x-axis are formatted differently because they have more space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I found a solution.

Add the following line to your code:

```
ax.YAxis.TickLabelFormat = '%d';
```

[I don't know why `ax.YAxis.Exponent = 0;` doesn't work]